# Oracle RDF table throws ORA-22835 error when saving triple

Tags: java, oracle, rdf, jena, sqlexception

We're running a Java application that saves data to the Oracle RDF triplestore using the Jena adapter.  Our version of Oracle is 11gR2.

Recently, we've been getting this error popping up during the save of a large triple.

```
ERROR http-bio-8080-exec-4 oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.GraphOracleSem:
Could not add triple java.sql.SQLException: 
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 5223, maximum: 4000)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.sendBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3753)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3444)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
        at oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.GraphOracleSem.performAdd(GraphOracleSem.java:3509)
        at oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.OracleBulkUpdateHandler.add(OracleBulkUpdateHandler.java:1226)
        at oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.OracleBulkUpdateHandler.addIterator(OracleBulkUpdateHandler.java:1257)
        at oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.OracleBulkUpdateHandler.add(OracleBulkUpdateHandler.java:1278)
        at oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.OracleBulkUpdateHandler.add(OracleBulkUpdateHandler.java:1268)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateProcessorVisitor$1.exec(UpdateProcessorVisitor.java:51)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.GraphStoreUtils.action(GraphStoreUtils.java:60)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateProcessorVisitor.visit(UpdateProcessorVisitor.java:48)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.op.UpdateInsertData.visit(UpdateInsertData.java:16)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateProcessorMain.execute(UpdateProcessorMain.java:34)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateAction.execute(UpdateAction.java:253)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateAction.parseExecute(UpdateAction.java:176)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateAction.parseExecute(UpdateAction.java:143)
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateAction.parseExecute(UpdateAction.java:105)
```

As the error states, it occurs when the data string is greater than 4000 characters.  Though it doesn't specify table/column in the error, the Oracle documentation suggests that it's supposed to automatically handle this internally:

> RDF_VALUE$ Table:
>
> LONG_VALUE: CLOB - The character string if the length of the lexical value is greater than 4000 bytes. Otherwise, this column has a null value.
>
> VALUE_NAME: VARCHAR2(4000) - This is a computed column. If length of the lexical value is 4000 bytes or less, the value of this column is the concatenation of the values of VNAME_PREFIX column and the VNAME_SUFFIX column.

Some users are not seeing this error, though it may be that they just haven't tried to save something big enough.  We've tried clearing out the triplestore model of the user, which seemed to work for a couple days but then came back.

Does anybody have any hints about where to start debugging this?  Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess it's a bug in Oracle's RDF store.

Comment: I'd also guess you do not have the T4CTTIoer.java source, right? ;-)

Comment: Are you using graph.getBulkUpdateHandler().addInBulk(...)?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem a couple of years ago. Which version of the jena-adapter are you using? I got a patch that solved the problem, maybe you can try and see if it is still availiable on oracle support. This is the instruction I received:

1. login to support.oracle.com,
2. then click on Patches & Updates tab
3. in Patch Search panel, click Search tab, type 10186312 in the text box after Patch Name or Number button.
4. Click Search button. It should return one match.
5. Click on the Patch Name 10186312, then Click on Download.